# how to send a user back a directory using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

okay say I have www.example.com/1/2/

(I can add an index.html if it's needed to make it easier)

However, I want to make sure that the user will get redirected back to this if the above link gets typed in.

www.example.com/1/index.php

(probably didn't need the index.php ?)

I've looked at htaccess generators, and it didn't work...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_alias`

```
Redirect permanent /1/2/ http://example.com/1/
```

or `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^1/2/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/1/
```

Add one of the examples to the .htaccess-file in www.example.com/